# Не работает callback_handler в aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
from aiogram.types import ContentTypes, InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton

from db_api.database import Database
from config import token, db_name

from blanks.bot_texts import start_text
from blanks.bot_markups import get_contact_markup

from states_handlers.bot_states import RegistrationStates, AdminStates
from states_handlers.get_contact_handler import get_contact_handler
from states_handlers.get_fullname_handler import get_fullname_handler
from states_handlers.get_gender_handler import get_gender_handler
from states_handlers.get_age_handler import get_age_handler
from states_handlers.get_avatar_handler import get_avatar_handler
from states_handlers.get_region_handler import get_region_handler
from states_handlers.get_company_handler import get_company_handler

from admins_functions.admin_handler import admin_handler
from admins_functions.admin_callback_handler import admin_callback_handler
from admins_functions.add_partner_handler import add_partner_handler
from admins_functions.add_admin_handler import add_admin_handler

from auc_callback import auc_callback
from blanks.bot_markups import admin_markup
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level="INFO")
class AucBot:
    def __init__(self, token, db_name):
        self.bot = Bot(token)
        self.dp = Dispatcher(self.bot, storage=MemoryStorage())
        self.db = Database(db_name)

async def start_handler(self, message, state):
    m = await self.bot.send_message(
        chat_id="@jojojopa3000",
        text="пример",
        reply_markup=InlineKeyboardMarkup().add(InlineKeyboardButton(
            text="⚠️", callback_data="warning")
    ))
    print(m.message_id)

    m = await self.bot.send_message(
        chat_id=message.chat.id,
        text="пример",
        reply_markup=InlineKeyboardMarkup().add(InlineKeyboardButton(
            text="⚠️", callback_data="warning")
        ))
    # await self.bot.edit_message_text(
    #     chat_id="@jojojopa3000",
    #     text="изменённый пример",
    #     message_id=404,
    #     reply_markup=InlineKeyboardMarkup().add(InlineKeyboardButton(
    #     text="⚠️", callback_data="warning"
    # )
    #     )
    # )
    await state.finish()
    tg_id = message.from_user.id
    blocked_users = self.db.get_blocked_users()
    if tg_id in blocked_users:
        await self.bot.send_message(
            chat_id=tg_id,
            text="К сожалению вы заблокированы"
        )

    else:
        chat = message.chat.id
        tg_id = message.from_user.id
        registered_users = self.db.get_registered_users()

        if tg_id in registered_users:
            pass

        else:
            await RegistrationStates.phone.set()
            await self.bot.send_message(
                chat_id=chat,
                text=start_text,
                reply_markup=get_contact_markup
            )

#{"message_id": 4, "from": {"id": 1283802964, "is_bot": false, "first_name": "Алексей", "last_name": "Смирнов", "username": "Tredikt", "language_code": "ru"}, "chat": {"id": -1001985774888, "title": "Шинный аукцион. Группа", "type": "supergroup"}, "date": 1694618860, "text": "."}

async def text_handler(self, message, state):
    print(await state.get_state())
    tg_id = message.from_user.id
    blocked_users = self.db.get_blocked_users()
    if tg_id in blocked_users:
        await self.bot.send_message(
            chat_id=tg_id,
            text="К сожалению вы заблокированы"
        )
    chat = message.chat.id

    if chat == -1001985774888:
        text = message.text
        print(text)
        text_list = text.split("\n")
        print(text_list)
        name = text_list[1].split(":")[1].strip()
        model = text_list[2].split(":")[1].strip()
        code = text_list[3].split(":")[1].strip()
        season = text_list[4].split(":")[1].strip()
        tires = text_list[5].split(":")[1].strip()
        disks = text_list[6].split(":")[1].strip()
        price = text_list[7].split(":")[1].strip()
        photo = text_list[8].split(":", 1)[1].strip()

        print(name, model, code, season, tires, disks, price, photo)
        self.db.add_lot(name, model, code, season, tires, disks, price, photo)

def register_handlers(self):
    self.dp.register_message_handler(callback=self.start_handler, commands=["start"], state="*")
    self.dp.register_message_handler(callback=get_contact_handler, content_types=ContentTypes.CONTACT, state=RegistrationStates.phone)
    self.dp.register_message_handler(callback=get_fullname_handler, content_types=ContentTypes.TEXT, state=RegistrationStates.fullname)
    self.dp.register_message_handler(callback=get_gender_handler, content_types=ContentTypes.TEXT, state=RegistrationStates.gender)
    self.dp.register_message_handler(callback=get_age_handler, content_types=ContentTypes.TEXT, state=RegistrationStates.age)
    self.dp.register_message_handler(callback=get_avatar_handler, content_types=ContentTypes.ANY, state=RegistrationStates.avatar)
    self.dp.register_callback_query_handler(callback=get_region_handler, state=RegistrationStates.region)
    self.dp.register_message_handler(callback=get_company_handler, content_types=ContentTypes.TEXT, state=RegistrationStates.company)

    # self.dp.register_message_handler(callback=admin_handler, commands=["admin"], state="*")
    self.dp.register_message_handler(callback=self.text_handler, content_types=ContentTypes.TEXT, state="*")

    self.dp.register_callback_query_handler(callback=admin_callback_handler, state="*")
    self.dp.register_message_handler(callback=add_partner_handler, state=AdminStates.add_partner, content_types=["text", "contact"])
    self.dp.register_message_handler(callback=add_admin_handler, state=AdminStates.add_admin, content_types=["text", "contact"])

    self.dp.register_callback_query_handler(callback=auc_callback, state="*")

def run(self):
    self.register_handlers()
    executor.start_polling(dispatcher=self.dp, skip_updates=True)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    bot = AucBot(token=token, db_name=db_name)
    bot.run()
```

Проблема в том, что callback_handler вообще никак не реагирует
код callback

```
async def auc_callback(call, state):
    print(1)
    chat = call.message.chat.id
    m_id = call.message.message_id
    bot, db = get_bot_and_db()
    callback = call.data

print(call)
tg_id = call.message["from"].id
blocked_users = db.get_blocked_users()
if tg_id in blocked_users:
    await bot.send_message(
        chat_id=tg_id,
        text="К сожалению вы заблокированы"
    )

elif callback == "warning":
    print("aboba")
    await call.answer(text="Если победитель откажется от лота, он передается следующему участнику")

elif callback[:4] == "time":
    code = int(callback.split("_")[1])
    minutes, hours = db.get_start_lot_time(code)
    now_minutes = datetime.now().minute
    now_hours = datetime.now().hour

    time = (now_hours * 60 + now_minutes) - (hours * 60 + minutes)
    await call.answer(text=f"До конца аукциона {time} минут")
```